# JW HLS streaming with hd button

Tags: jwplayer, m3u8

Folks,

I am using JW premium edition in my website, I want to stream my VOD contents using JW player in all devices, laptops and desktops with HD button shows multiple flavors.

I used this code to show the player,

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jwplayer('myElement').setup({
        playlist: [{
                image:"poster.jpg",

                sources: [{
              file: "http://54.84.148.121/mediacache/_definst_/mp4:kalturanew/content/entry/data/0/0/0_piphfrui_0_fkzp15ye_1.mp4/playlist.m3u8",
              label: "720p SD"
            },{file: "http://54.84.148.121/mediacache/_definst_/mp4:kalturanew/content/entry/data/0/0/0_piphfrui_0_5gg8sfep_1.mp4/playlist.m3u8",
              label: "560p SD"
            }]

           }],            
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",
            abouttext: "Konnect+"
          });
    </script>
```

But I am not getting hd button in the player control bar.

However I used the myManifest.m3u8 file as stated in http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29393/hls-adaptive-stream/

```
    <div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jwplayer('myElement').setup({
        playlist: [{
                image:"Biryani-Release-poster.jpg",
                file: "myManifest.m3u8"
           }],            
            height: "55%",
            width: "50%",
            abouttext: "Konnect+"
          });
    </script>
```

myManifest.m3u8:

```
    #EXTM3U
    #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=160000,RESOLUTION=480x256 1280/http://54.84.148.121/mediacache/_definst_/mp4:kalturanew/content/entry/data/0/0/0_piphfrui_0_fkzp15ye_1.mp4/playlist.m3u8
    #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=83200,RESOLUTION=480x256 640/http://54.84.148.121/mediacache/_definst_/mp4:kalturanew/content/entry/data/0/0/0_piphfrui_0_5gg8sfep_1.mp4/playlist.m3u8
```

This says its not valid m3ub: no levels to play..
Here is the link http://uniqueegroup.com/hlsTest.html

Can anyone suggest me a right way?

Thanks

Comment: http://uniqueegroup.com/hlsTest.html is just using one level. You absolutely need to use an HLS manifest. Our demo page that you linked to above has this sample that you can use as a template - http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/bbbfull/bbbfull.m3u8

Comment: I have changed the manifest now in the above URL, Even now also it couldn't get the hd button. Can you please check it now?  http://uniqueegroup.com/hlsTest.html

Comment: I get a Flash debug player error now - Error: No TS fragments found in Playlist: http://54.84.148.121/mediacache/_definst_/mp4:kalturanew/content/entry/data/0/0/0_piphfrui_0_fkzp15ye_1.mp4/playlist.m3u8

Comment: Can you please help me what needs to be rectified?

Comment: Does this file work when you try it by itself? http://54.84.148.121/mediacache/_definst_/mp4:kalturanew/content/entry/data/0/0/0_piphfrui_0_fkzp15ye_1.mp4/playlist.m3u8

Comment: Sure, FYI Please test here....http://uniqueegroup.com/hlsTest.html

Comment: Yes, that file works. I would try to set up your main manifest with relative paths to the m3u8 files, instead of absolute.

Comment: Thanks, Is there anything I need to do in my end?

Comment: Yes, just make your main mainfile file use relative urls instead of absolute.

Comment: Not sure how to do that, as I am new to this. Can you please let me know any syntax format of the manifest file you looking for?

Comment: For example you have the full http paths in your manifest file for each, they should be relative paths instead, not full http, absolute, paths.

Comment: May I know how this would be written?54.84.148.121/mediacache/_definst_/mp4:kalturanew/content/entry/data/0/0/0_piphfrui_0_fkzp15ye_1.mp4/playlist.m3u8

Comment: Just the last sections "0_piphfrui_0_fkzp15ye_1.mp4/playlist.m3u8"

Comment: But where to place rest of the contents (54.84.148.121/mediacache/_definst_/mp4:kalturanew/content/entry/data/0/0‌​)?..... Please check the below manifest and please lemme know this is right.http://uniqueegroup.com/myManifest.m3u8.... The page shows nothing and loading always http://uniqueegroup.com/hlsTest.html

Comment: I would make the main manifest on 54.84.148.121, then point the chunks relatively to the location of the main manifest file, if that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for your patient indeed. I dont know I can answer this much silly questions for a person. Please can I have a sample main manifest and child manifest please. I am very new to this.

Comment: http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/bbbfull/bbbfull.m3u8 is the only one I have

Comment: But it says some error when I tried with that m3u8

Comment: I am using the same file which downloaded by the url above... It is http://uniqueegroup.com/bbbfull.m3u8 The page FYI http://uniqueegroup.com/hlsJW.html

Comment: Those sub m3u8 files need to exist on your server, too.

Comment: please check my page here http://uniqueegroup.com/hlsJW.html

Comment: Confused lot....    please check my page here uniqueegroup.com/hlsJW.html       My Main manifest file as you suggested here please check my page here uniqueegroup.com/hlsJW.html   relative files here http://uniqueegroup.com/bbbfull640x360.m3u8   http://uniqueegroup.com/bbbfull1280x720.m3u8    http://uniqueegroup.com/bbbfull320x180.m3u8    please help me... totally confused about the manifest......

Comment: Where are you running the manifest in the player?

Comment: file: "bbbfull.m3u8" , can you please check the source code http://uniqueegroup.com/hlsJW.html

Comment: I get the same error - Error: No TS fragments found in Playlist: http://uniqueegroup.com/bbbfull320x180.m3u8, again, http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/bbbfull/bbbfull.m3u8 is the main on we use on our server, and it works fine.

Comment: Where I want to put my main manifest for this URL  uniqueegroup.com/hlsJW.html    ..........................  https://d2jtqpvtg13w20.cloudfront.net/mediacache/_definst_/mp4:kalturanew/content/entry/data/0/0/0_t0ph581w_0_179ybh0k_1.mp4/playlist.m3u8..................................................................I think main manifest under here https://d2jtqpvtg13w20.cloudfront.net/mediacache/_definst_/mp4:kalturanew/content/entry/data/0/0/ ..................................... and need to point relative urls 0_t0ph581w_0_179ybh0k_1.mp4        Am I right?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you are asking here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after the .m3u8 you have to use the following

?dimension=720p rather than 1280/http as it will not detect the http url in your m3u8.I have checked your demo and it will work when you will make this correction.